# I want to get the sum of three numbers without using + or * symbols

Tags: javascript, function, variables, console, return

I don't want use any + or * in my function, so I put "var sum1 = a+b" as a global variable
then I put it in "var sumAB" to add to it the argument "c".
but I don't know what it is not working?

hint:- I don't want to make var sum1 = a+b+c.

```
var sum1 = a+b //global variable

function sumAndMultiply (a, b, c){

    var sumAndMulArray = [];
    var sumAb = (sum1, c)[0];
    var finalSum = (sumAb)[0];
    return sumAndMulArray[0] = finalSum
    console.log(sumAndMultiply); 
}
SumAndMultiply(4,7,5);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use these operators? Can you use a minus operator? Subtracting the negation of a number is the same as addition, so you could do `a - -b`, which technically doesn't use the addition operator.

Comment: There are just too many problems with this code for a single solution. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what is your purpose for this line of codes `var sumAb = (sum1, c)[0];`? Get the value of **sum1** plus **c**?

Comment: @Sphinx yes, is that right syntax?

Comment: @zeterain can you tell me please how to approach this problem with my instruction, with my current code.

Comment: @Sphinx his solution is correct but my solution in adding "c" with this way "var sumAb = (sum1, c)[0]; " is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems very strange not to use the characters `+` or `-` in your function. It appears that it is fine to use them in the outer program though, for example in your declaration `var sum1 = a+b`. If the only requirement is that the function `sumAndMultiply` doesn't contain `+` or `-`, then you could just write another function to define your custom syntax for addition:

```
function sum(n1,n2){
return(n1+n2);
}
function sumAndMultiply (a, b, c){
return(sum(sum(a,b),c));
}
console.log(sumAndMultiply(4,7,5));
```

This all seems unnecessarily complicated though. It would be easier just to use javascript's simple, native syntax. 
On a side note, the `console.log` in your original code will never be executed, since the function exits when it sees the `return` statement on the line above. Put any code you want to be executed before your `return` statement. Also, javascript is case sensitive, so calling `SumAndMultiply` with a capital won't call the lowercase `sumAndMultiply` function.

Comment: I have an assignment that tells me that. thank you for your solution

Comment: But please can you tell me my solution is correct or not in adding **c** with this way  **var sumAb = (sum1, c)[0];** is this a wrong syntax?

Comment: The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) returns only the last value. Thus `(foo,c)` would return only c. You can't read it with square brackets. Just try testing something like `(1,2)[0]` in the console. It will return undefined. So yes, your syntax as it stands is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the purpose of your assignment is let you implement **+ operator** by **bit operator**.

Below is one sample:

```js
function add (num1, num2) {
    if(num2 == 0) return num1;
    let sum = num1 ^ num2;
    let carry = (num1 & num2) << 1;
    return add(sum, carry);
}

function sumAndMultiply (a, b, c){
  return add(a, add(b, c))
}
console.log(sumAndMultiply(4, 7, 5))
console.log(sumAndMultiply(24, 77, 105))
```

Comment: what is "^"  ,and "<< 1" is used for ?

Comment: open [Javascript operators in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators), then scroll down, you will see **Bitwise shift operators** and **Binary bitwise operators**

Comment: but please can you tell me my solution is correct or not in adding **c** with this way  **var sumAb = (sum1, c)[0];** is this a wrong syntax?

Comment: Bitwise operators as used by Sphinx are the basis of how computers add numbers on a low level. See [this](http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/Crypto/Lab1/BinAdd.html) explanation of addition in binary, and look through the MDN docs to see which operators do what. You could also look up an adder circuit for an explanation of how these things work electronically.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const getSum = (a, b, c) => {
        var _a = new Array(a).fill(true);
        var _b = new Array(b).fill(true);
        var _c = new Array(c).fill(true);

        return _a.concat(_b, _c).length
    }
    console.log(getSum(10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: Can you please, explain in simple words line by line what you did, because I really a beginner in web development.

Comment: At begining I use fill function because it create a array repiting true the num asig for example var _a = new Array(3).fill(true) its the same [true, true, true] and at the end I just concat the lenght of the arrays

Comment: If you want more explanation about fill function you can see it in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/fill)